# Why My Postgresql query could not find the data in Net Core 6?

Tags: c#, dapper, npgsql, postgresql-14

I have a query of Postgresql-14 as below, the record was found if I run it on DBeaver 23.1.4.

I use:

- Dapper 2.0.143
- Npgsql 7.0.4
- `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` 7.0.4

Additional info:

`process_datetime` and `start_datetime` are of datatype `timestamptz`.

What I don't understand is why it works properly on DBeaver 23.1.4?

I copy the query into a string variable named "sql", but I did not find the record if I run it on my Net Core 6 (C#) code, what I missed?

```
select 
    t.organizations_pid, 
    coalesce(sum(t.sum_usage),0) * 1.05 totalUsage,   
    coalesce(count(t.iccid), 0) numSIMs 
from 
    (select 
         s.organizations_pid, c2.pid cdrs_pid, c2.cdr_id,  
         c2.iccid, c2.network, c1.sum_usage, 
         c2.start_datetime, c2.status 
     from
         (select 
              s.organizations_pid, c1.iccid, 
              sum(c1.usage) sum_usage, max(c1.process_datetime) max_process_datetime 
          from 
              cdrs c1 
          inner join 
              sims s on c1.iccid = s.iccid 
          where 
              s.organizations_pid = 29 
              and to_char(c1.start_datetime,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2023-08-01' 
              and to_char(c1.start_datetime,'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2023-08-07' 
              and c1.is_beginbal = false 
          group by 
              s.organizations_pid, c1.iccid) c1 
     inner join 
         cdrs c2 on c2.process_datetime = c1.max_process_datetime 
                 and c2.iccid = c1.iccid 
     inner join 
         sims s on c2.iccid = s.iccid 
                and s.last_cdr_id = c2.cdr_id
     inner join 
         organizations o on s.organizations_pid = o.pid 
     where 
         s.organizations_pid = 29 
         and s.attributes->'subscription'->> 'subscriptionStatus' = 'ACTIVE') t 
group by 
    t.organizations_pid
```

My C# code is below:

```
using (var dr = conn.ExecuteReader(sql, new { }))
{
   if (dr.Read())
   {
     double totalUsage = dr.GetDouble(dr.GetOrdinal("totalUsage"));
   }
}
```

I also have tried below, but result returns null.

```
var result = conn.Query(sql, new { }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Not working - what does it mean exactly? Do you get an exception?

Comment: it did not find the record

Comment: `and to_char(c1.start_datetime,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2023-08-01'` is guaranteed to cause problems. If `start_datetime` is a date-typed column, convert the parameter to a date, not the field. Better yet, use date-typed parameters instead of strings. Converting the *field* prevents the database from using any indexes

Comment: If `start_datetime` isn't a date field, `to_char` has no effect and returns whatever text is stored in the column. It would be no different than `and start_datetime> '2023-08-01`. That query will only work if the stored text and filter patterns match. That's a table design bug - dates should be stored in date-typed columns.

Comment: If it works in DBeaver, it should work here as well. Why are you using DataReader? Use Dapper Query<T>. e.g.,  var result = connection.Query<YourResultType>(sql).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: I have tried:

var xxx = conn.QueryFirstOrDefault(sql, new {} );

but it returns null

Comment: I also have tried:

I have tried:

var result = conn.Query(sql, new { }).SingleOrDefault();

but it returns null

Comment: Side note: you can massively improve this query by using window functions https://dbfiddle.uk/fVEgGHtH

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this by changing the

```
to_char(c1.start_datetime,'YYYY-MM-DD') >=
```

to

```
DATE_TRUNC('day',c.start_datetime at TIME zone 'UTC') >=
```